# Broken dependencies to encoding pkg. Code not working from one day to the other. Failed upgrade? (EDIT: No! failed user. Please see my answer)

Tags: go

I am new to Golang and am developing a web scraping program. Last night I was running my programs and all was OK. My programs ran both from source code using "go run xyz.go", or a built version ($ ./xyz.exe)

This morning I woke up to an apparent broken dependency problem that I have not managed to figure out. The built program (./xyz.exe) from last night still runs, but when I try to run the source code today using "go run xyz.go" I get the following result:

"$ go run xyz.go

go build golang.org/x/text/encoding: no non-test Go files in C:\Users\admin\Dropbox\gowork\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\encoding

go build golang.org/x/text/transform: no non-test Go files in C:\Users\admin\Dropbox\gowork\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\transform

golang.org/x/net/html/atom

........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\net@v0.0.0-20210916014120-12bc252f5db8\html\atom\atom.go:27:26: undefined: atomText
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\net@v0.0.0-20210916014120-12bc252f5db8\html\atom\atom.go:30:9: undefined: atomText
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\net@v0.0.0-20210916014120-12bc252f5db8\html\atom\atom.go:34:9: undefined: atomText
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\net@v0.0.0-20210916014120-12bc252f5db8\html\atom\atom.go:58:29: undefined: maxAtomLen
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\net@v0.0.0-20210916014120-12bc252f5db8\html\atom\atom.go:61:11: undefined: hash0
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\net@v0.0.0-20210916014120-12bc252f5db8\html\atom\atom.go:62:10: undefined: table
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\net@v0.0.0-20210916014120-12bc252f5db8\html\atom\atom.go:65:10: undefined: table

github.com/andybalholm/cascadia

........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:10:9: undefined: tagSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:14:9: undefined: idSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:18:9: undefined: classSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:22:9: undefined: attrSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:32:9: undefined: relativePseudoClassSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:35:9: undefined: containsPseudoClassSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:42:9: undefined: regexpPseudoClassSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:49:9: undefined: nthPseudoClassSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:75:9: undefined: onlyChildPseudoClassSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:81:9: undefined: inputPseudoClassSelector
........\pkg\mod\github.com\andybalholm\cascadia@v1.2.0\serialize.go:81:9: too many errors

golang.org/x/text/internal/language

........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\compact.go:12:23: undefined: Tag
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\compact.go:23:32: undefined: Tag
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\compose.go:15:6: undefined: Tag
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\compose.go:23:26: undefined: Tag
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\compose.go:56:28: undefined: Tag
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\coverage.go:9:24: undefined: Language
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\match.go:17:10: undefined: Tag
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\match.go:17:35: undefined: Language
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\match.go:23:10: undefined: Tag
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\match.go:23:37: undefined: Script
........\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\internal\language\match.go:23:37: too many errors"

I tried to solve this by upgrading to the latest version of Golang. Not sure if that made things worse.

I am using the encoding/csv package. My IDE is Visual Sudio Code. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv" // Problem seems to be with this package
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {

    fName := "FOOT-live-data.csv"
    file, err := os.OpenFile(fName, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("No se pudo crear archivo, error: %q", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    writer := csv.NewWriter(file) // Package encoding/csv is used here
    defer writer.Flush()
    
    liga := ""
    start := time.Now()
    cons := 0
    eventodds := make([]string, 3, 5)
    var data [][]string

    c := colly.NewCollector()
    
    c.OnHTML(`div#USInplay-tab-FOOT div.table-row.row-wrap`, func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {

        if e.DOM.Children().Length() == 1 {
            if liga != e.ChildText(`div.ev-type-header`) {
                liga = e.ChildText(`div.ev-type-header`)
            }
        } else {
            cons = cons + 1
            timestamp := time.Now().Round(time.Second)
            eventid := e.Attr("data-mkt_id")
            eventinfo := strings.Split(e.ChildText(`div[class="team-score"]`), "\n")
            eventtime := e.ChildText(`span.clock_mode_forward`)
            eventperiod := e.ChildText(`span.period`)

            e.ForEach(`div.inplay td.seln`, func(i int, elem *colly.HTMLElement) {
                eventodds[i] = elem.ChildText(`span.dec`)
            })

            data = append(data, []string{
                timestamp.Format(time.RubyDate),
                "WPlay",
                liga,
                eventid,
                eventinfo[1] + " - " + eventinfo[4],
                eventinfo[0] + "-" + eventinfo[3],
                eventtime,
                eventperiod,
                eventodds[0],
                eventodds[1],
                eventodds[2],
            })

        }

    })

    c.Visit("https://apuestas.wplay.co/es")

    writer.WriteAll(data)

    log.Printf("Scraping finished, check file %q for results\n", fName)

    secs := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    fmt.Printf("Tiempo total: %v segs", secs)
}
```

Comment: Don't use `go run` - use `go build`

Comment: Thanks. The problem was not there. The problem was my clumsy and uneducated use of Github. Please see my own answer hereunder.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out this odd situation! I debated between deleting my stupid question, or answer it myself to help someone else in a similar situation. I decided to bite the public derision bullet and answer it myself.

The problem was indeed related to a broken dependency, but not to the encoding package. The root cause of the problem is my clumsy use of Github.

I work mostly on this computer, and I have created a Github rep to save my work and to replicate it in two computers more, one laptop for the road and an old Mac.

Surely enough a couple of weeks ago I was on a business trip and worked on my project one night. I had problems with the Colly package on THAT machine, so I deleted it from the src and pkg folders, which are in sync with the Github rep. Then, mechanically and "neuronlessly", I synced my work with Github as I always do at the end of my journey.

Back to my usual computer, I did perform some more work, and did sync with my Guthub rep. When I got the warning of not "pushing" my work before "pulling" or ignoring latest version from the Github rep, I did not give it a second thought before "pulling" from the rep first.

Boom! The deleted Colly folder from my on-the-road laptop made it all the way into this machine, via Github. It made a mess on my Colly folder on this machine that I am still trying to untangle.

I also realized that there is no point on syncing the bin, pkg and src folders with Github, since only the latter contains the actual code you care for, and the other two are populated locally if content doesn't exist; they are specific to the machine and architecture you are working on. Which I am now almost certain created the problem on my laptop on the first place.

This confirms the saying that you learn more from your mistakes than your successes!

Again, I apologize for having posted the question without exhausting every last resource. I hope the conclusion of it is helpful.